# How to remove specific part of string from each item of array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

Given the following:

```
var arr = [
    "one,two,three",
    "four,five,six,seven",
    "eight,nine,ten",
    "11,12,13,14"
];
```

What's the best way to remove the second word from each element in the array? The desired output of the array would be:

```
arr = [
    "one,three",
    "four,six,seven",
    "eight,ten",
    "11,13,14"
];
```

I felt the most logical approach would be to use a for loop to cycle through the array and remove index 1 from each element, like as follows:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    i.splice(1,1).join(';');
}
```

(within the loop, I also tried `arr[i].splice(1,1).join(';');`) --- but neither approach is returning the desired outcome. What am I doing wrong and what's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: do you want the output to be an array with the removed elements, right?

Answer (score 4):

You need to split the array first and then remove the element.

```js
var arr = [
  "one,two,three",
  "four,five,six,seven",
  "eight,nine,ten",
  "11,12,13,14"
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // split the string based on ,
  var a = arr[i].split(',');
  // remove second element from string
  a.splice(1, 1);
  // join the updated string array
  arr[i] = a.join();
}

console.log(arr);
```

---

Or another method using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) methods.

```js
var arr = [
  "one,two,three",
  "four,five,six,seven",
  "eight,nine,ten",
  "11,12,13,14"
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // get the index of first ,
  var index = arr[i].indexOf(','),
    // get the index of second index
    index1 = arr[i].indexOf(',', index + 1);
  // generate the string based on index
  arr[i] = arr[i].slice(0, index) + arr[i].slice(index1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression for the string, which looks for a comma, any character, non gready and for another comma, which is not included for replacing.

```js
var arr = ["one,two,three", "four,five,six,seven", "eight,nine,ten", "11,12,13,14"];

arr = arr.map(function (a) {
    return a.replace(/,.*?(?=,)/, '');
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must break your strings in arrays so:

```
elements = arr[i].split(',');
```

then you splice the second element and join the string back:

```
elements.splice(1,1)
result = elements.join(',');
```

lastly you replace the string with the new one:

```
arrs[i] = result
```

To wrap up:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    elements = arrs[i].split(',');
    elements.splice(1,1);
    arrs[i] = elements.join(',');
}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.prototype.splice` function returns the removed items(s).

You need to store the array, remove the items(s), and finally return the array.

```js
var arr = [
  "one,two,three",
  "four,five,six,seven",
  "eight,nine,ten",
  "11,12,13,14"
];

function spliceWords(arr, pos, length) {
  length = length || 1; // Default number to remove is 1.
  return arr.map(function(item) {
    var words = item.split(',');
    words.splice(pos, length); // Splice removes the items in-place.
    return words.join(',');
  });
}

var arr2 = spliceWords(arr, 1);

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr2, null, 4);
```

```css
body { font-family:monospace; white-space:pre; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
arr.map(x => x.replace(x.match(/,[^,]*/),""))
```

Or

```
arr.map(function(x) x.replace(x.match(/,[^,]*/),""))
```

Result:

```
["one,three", "four,six,seven", "eight,ten", "11,13,14"]
```

The regular expression looks for the first comma (`,`) and grabs everything that follows that is *not* a comma (`[^,]*`). This part of the string will be replaced by nothing (`""`).

The `map` method will apply this function to every element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to changing every item of array, and use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to removing second value from string.

```js
var arr = [
    "one,two,three",
    "four,five,six,seven",
    "eight,nine,ten",
    "11,12,13,14"
];

arr = arr.map(function(val){
    return val.replace(/([\w]+),[\w]+,(.*)/, "$1,$2");
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through each element in array
2. Use the split() method to create array of comma separated element
3. use splice() method to remove 2nd part in the array

Here is the algorithm:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
var a = arr[i].split(",");  
a.splice(1,1);  
arr[i] = a.join();  
}
```